# Slider Input Value to Change Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not sure how I change an image, based on the input of a slider, I just cannot seem to get the if statement to work. I have taken the section out of the web page I was working on. In this example I tried to change the image when the value equals 60. Eventually I would like to delete the number from the html.

P.s I took the slider from w3school on the link. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp
The only thing I have added is the If statement and that is the only thing that doesn't work.

Thanks for reading.

[html]

```
<p>Select Fat Level</p>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
        <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
    </div>

    <img src="images/bodytype/fat01muscle01.png" id="quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image">
</center>
```

[css]

```
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%; /* Width of the outside container */
}

/* The slider itself */
.slider {
-webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default CSS styles */
appearance: none;
width: 100%; /* Full-width */
height: 25px; /* Specified height */
background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
outline: none; /* Remove outline */
opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
-webkit-transition: .2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
transition: opacity .2s;
}

/* Mouse-over effects */
.slider:hover {
opacity: 1; /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}

/* The slider handle (use -webkit- (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and -moz- 
(Firefox) to override default look) */ 
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
appearance: none;
width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}
```

[js]

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)

    slider.oninput = function() {
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }

    if (output.value==60) {
        alert("hi")
        document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src("images/bodytype/fat02muscle01.png");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on that code, the if statement is only called on the initial page load. try moving it into the event handler and checking the slider value, not the output value:

```
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  if(this.value == 60){
  alert("hi")
  document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src("images/bodytype/fat02muscle01.png");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the IF statement now works for the testing alert, however it didn't change the image, any idea why?

Comment: You need to set it as a value:                                       `document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src = "images/bodytype/fat02muscle01.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

if you console.log `output.value` will undefined. so you need to get the value of range with `this.value`. Also, you need to change this code `.src("images/bodytype/fat02muscle01.png");` to this `.src="images/bodytype/fat02muscle01.png";` base on https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)

slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;

    if (this.value==60) {
    alert("hi")
    document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="http://pngriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Download-Free-Free-Download-PNG.png";
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I want to make this more advanced by having the two inputs work together. E.g. when the value of slider 1 is 10 and slider 2 is 20 a certain image appears, but when I try this the two sliders do not worker individually.

Comment: You need to add a global variable, and then set value of the variable for the first range. On the second range used the variable to check the value. You can use if else...

Comment: Apologies, I am new to coding, could you show an example?